# variable showing strange value when implementing NLMS algorithm in Android

Tags: java, android, signal-processing, audio-processing

I have been scratching my head about this all day and have run out of ideas now, so I am posting this here

I am trying to implement a feedback suppressor in Android using the [NLMS algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_mean_squares_filter)
I use an AudioRecord to obtain audio samples from the MIC and AudioTrack to play it back. I read in 1 sample at a time as a short variable, convert it to double, pass it through my algorithm, convert it back to short and send it to the speaker. However, I am getting weird values in the intermediate variable and canot understand why it is happening. Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    AudioManager am = null;
    AudioRecord record =null;
    AudioTrack track =null;
    final int SAMPLE_FREQUENCY = 16000; // ORIGINAL 44100
    final int SIZE_OF_RECORD_ARRAY = 1;     // 1024 ORIGINAL; 1000 / 40 = 25
    // final int WAV_SAMPLE_MULTIPLICATION_FACTOR = 1;
    final double WAV_SAMPLE_MULTIPLICATION_FACTOR = 0.5;
    final int N = 4; // ORIGINAL 40
    final int FEEDBACK_DELAY_IN_MSEC = 1;   // use small integer values here to keep the calculation of NO_OF_DELAY_SAMPLES from becoming non-whole number
    // final int NO_OF_DELAY_SAMPLES = SAMPLE_FREQUENCY / (FEEDBACK_DELAY_IN_MSEC * 1000); // NO_OF_DELAY_SAMPLES = 16
    final int NO_OF_DELAY_SAMPLES = 0; 
    final int TOTAL_SIZE_OF_X = N + NO_OF_DELAY_SAMPLES;
    int i = 0, n = 0; // n represents nth sample
    boolean isPlaying = false; // represents if the Pass Through button is pressed
    boolean applyDsp = false; // represents if the Apply Filter button is pressed
    boolean bufferFull = false;
    private volatile boolean keepThreadRunning;
    double[] w = new double[N];     // w represents filter coefficients
    double[] x = new double[TOTAL_SIZE_OF_X];
    double e; 
    double d;
    double send_out;
    double mu;
    double y = 0;

    // /*
    private RandomAccessFile stateFile;
    String stateFileLoc = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
    FileDescriptor fd;
    // */

    class MyThread extends Thread{
        private volatile boolean needsToPassThrough;
        // /*
        MyThread(){
            super();
        }

        MyThread(boolean newPTV){
            this.needsToPassThrough = newPTV;
        }
        // */

        // /*
        @Override
        public void run(){
            short[] lin = new short[SIZE_OF_RECORD_ARRAY];
            short[] speaker = new short[SIZE_OF_RECORD_ARRAY];
            double speaker_double;
            int num = 0;
            Log.d("MYLOG", "ENTERED RUN");
            if(needsToPassThrough){
                record.startRecording();
                track.play();
                Log.d("MYLOG", "COMES HERE BEFORE BTN PRESS?");
            }
                        n = TOTAL_SIZE_OF_X -1;
            while (keepThreadRunning) { // thread runs until this loop stops; this loop runs as long as the program is running
                num = record.read(lin, 0, SIZE_OF_RECORD_ARRAY);
                for(i=0;i<lin.length;i++)
                    d = (double)lin[i];         // this line requires that lin[] has to be a single element array 
                if(isPlaying){
                    if(applyDsp){
                        y=0.0; // initialize every time
                        for(i=0; i<N; i++){
                           y += w[N-1-i] * x[n-i - NO_OF_DELAY_SAMPLES];
                        }

                        // Implementing step 2
                        e = d - y;

                        // /*
                        try {
                            stateFile.writeDouble(e);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        // Implementing step 3
                        mu = 0.5 / (x[n] * x[n] + 0.01);

                        // Implementing step 4
                        for(i=0; i<N; i++){
                               w[N-1-i] = w[N-1-i] + 2.0*mu*e*x[n-i - NO_OF_DELAY_SAMPLES];
                        }
                    } // closing of if(applyDsp) block

                    // Implementing step 5
                        for(i=0;i<TOTAL_SIZE_OF_X-1;i++){
                            x[i] = x[i+1];
                        }

                    send_out = e;   
                    speaker_double = send_out * WAV_SAMPLE_MULTIPLICATION_FACTOR;

                    // implementing step 6
                    x[TOTAL_SIZE_OF_X -1] = speaker_double;

                    for(i=0;i<speaker.length; i++)
                        speaker[i] = (short)speaker_double;

                    track.write(speaker, 0, num);
                } // if(isPlaying) block closed; this represents if the "Pass Through" button has been clicked

            } // while (keepThreadRunning) closes here; this infinite loop runs as long as the program is running 
            record.stop();
            track.stop();
            record.release();
            track.release();
        }

        public void stopThread(){
            keepThreadRunning = false;
        }

    } // End of MyThread class

    MyThread newThread;
```

I have just included that part of the code that contains the Thread which performs the NLMS to keep it short. Since `SIZE_OF_RECORD_ARRAY` is 1, the `lin` variable in `num = record.read(lin, 0, SIZE_OF_RECORD_ARRAY);` will always be a `short` array with just one element. (in fact, anu double or short array that may be encountered in the above code will just have a single element). the line `e = d - y` is key here. d is the value I get from the mic (d is short typecasted to double). During every run of the `while (keepThreadRunning) {` infinite loop, a new value for e should be calculated, which is later typecasted to short and passed to the AudioTrack. The problem is that `e` is not getting proper values in my case, and there is no output from the speakers. If I send the variable `d` to the AudioTrack, whatever input is spoken in to the microphone appears at the output (with a slight delay, but that is expected). If I try to write the `e` variable values to file, I am getting strange values. Since using `String.valueOf(e)` did not work out for me (each string character is considered as a 16-bit character and so `0` appears as `<space>0`, `-1` appears as `<space>-<space>1`), I directly wrote the double value to file using RandomAccessFile.write Double and viewed the file in a hex viewer. It seems that there is some random value at the beginning of the file, after which a pattern emerges, which I am not sure why it is there. A screenshot of the hex file is shown below:

[image]

The pattern shown continues till the end of file. Why is this happening? Since there was no output I assumed at least everything should have been 0, but as can be seen from this figure it's not 0 either, instead it is `7F F8 00 00 00 00 00 00` repeated again and again. Please help me determine why this is happening.

PS: The boolean values `isPlaying` and `applyDsp` represent the state of two buttons that I have on the interface. When I press the `applyDsp` button on the interface, the speaker makes a very short and relatively loud "pop" sound, which I assume may be the reason for the random values in the beginning of the file containing the values of `e` shown above, but I am not sure about this, and I am not sure abput why that popping noise is there in the first place.

Comment: Not java and not an answer, but a *much* simpler NLMS in Python is under [how-to-apply-an-adaptive-filter-in-python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18252160/how-to-apply-an-adaptive-filter-in-python) .

Comment: sorry but I have to do this in Android. I will check out your link as well though, it's possible these problems are because I haven't understood the NLMS algorithm properly.

Comment: Suggestion: you should really factor out the NLMS code into a separate class so that you can test/debug it in isolation (e.g. in a test harness). That way you can feed specific data into it, look at the output and see what's going on internally. Otherwise it's going to be pretty tough to debug.

Comment: Fwiw, [qpython.com](http://qpython.com/) is a Python for Android