Removing the Moving Component/Slope from a graph
I have a graph which slowly increases and there's a peak in the graph. This graph is derived from a numpy array. How can I make it a flat line like a ECG, with just the major peak?

I am thinking of trying out some kind of derivatives. But any help on how to proceed with it in python would be helpful.

we call that "highpass filtering"

take a look at functions in https://stackoverflow.com/a/57418729/4601890
